# Is it possible with CFDs to operate with 100% margin, so as to avoid overnight charges for a position left open overnight?

Tags: rollover

I have searched but have not been able to find one

Comment: voting to reopen because this is about how CFDs operate, we have plenty of discussions about derivatives especially options contracts, I don't see how a different standard can be applied to contracts for difference

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/43931/is-it-possible-to-trade-cfd-without-leverage

Comment: Updated to close, but as duplicate. Identical to the linked question.